# How the Nil is recognized in Scala as a method in List class

Tags: scala

I have the below line of code which constructs a list in Scala.

```
val oneTwoThree = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

It is explained that "The reason you need `Nil` at the end is that `::` is defined on class `List`. If you try to just say `1 :: 2 :: 3`, it won’t compile because 3 is an `Int`, which doesn’t have a `::` method."

But in the line of code, nowhere is the `List` class mentioned. Can someone please help me to understand how the `Nil` method in `List` class is then invoked correctly?

Answer (score 6):

`Nil` (see [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Nil$.html)) is a Scala object (singleton instance) that has a `::` method that returns a `List`.

Because of rules on method names that end with a colon, `3 :: Nil` is translated into `Nil.::(3)` and that returns `List(3)`. The `List` class also has a `::` method so `2 :: List(3)` is translated into `List(3).::(2)` which returns `List(2,3)`. And so on.

Comment: To summarize the calls with method name ending with colon is evaluated from right to left.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of `Nil` as just writing `[]` in Javascript for example.
It represents an empty list.

A simplified version of the List hierarchy is this:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A]

final case class ::[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
```

You don't see List in your example because you are using its children instead of List directly.

Note you can also create a list with `List(1, 2, 3)` instead because the List companion object also has an apply method with variable args:

```
object List {
  def apply[A](args: A*): List[A] = ...
}
```

The reason you absolutely need Nil in the line you have IS because it extends List.
The :: method (called Cons) is defined on the parent List trait, so lets update our version of it:

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] {
  def ::[B >: A](x: B): List[B] = ...
}
```

Now it might seem weird that Nil is at the end of the line, or at least on the right as you would normally use a method like `Nil.::` (which you can btw), but having `:` on the right is a Scala convention, that when you don't write `.` but use a space instead it will bind to the right argument instead of the left.  This gives it the backwards method call.

Take a look at [the Scala repo](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala) for the actual code.